# Identify pattern in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, classification, image-recognition

what is the best approach to identify a pattern (could be a text,signature, logo. **NOT** faces,objects,people,etc) in an image, given that all images are taken from the same angle, which means the pattern to identify will be ALWAYS visible at the same angle, but not position / size/ quality / brightness, etc.

Assuming I have the logo, I would like to run a test on 1000 images, from different sizes & quality and get those images that have this pattern embedded or at least a high probability to have this pattern embedded.

Thanks,

Comment: Please upload a few images ...

Comment: Pattern matching is one of the hardest problems in computer vision - good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl? I'd have suggested using OpenCV with python or C since you're on the Linux platform.

You could check out SURF and [SIFT](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/implementing-sift-in-opencv/) (explains how to do this with OpenCV and C++ with code attached) which can do decent template matching (logos, etc.).

Text detection is a different kettle of fish, I'd suggest [Robust Text Detection in Natural Images with Edge-enhanced maximally stable extremal regions](http://www.stanford.edu/~dmchen/documents/ICIP2011_RobustTextDetection.pdf) paper which is the latest I've seen that does robust text detection from natural scenes without becoming overly intricate.

Training a neural network with the expected patterns seems to be the best way all-round, though the training process will take a long time. Actual identification is almost real-time though.

[Here's a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152661/has-anyone-used-mser-in-opencv-to-detect-regions) on MSER implementation in two libraries: a) OpenCV, b) VLfeat

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can show a couple of images but it seems like [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) (perhaps with a [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform)) seems like an ideal candidate to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked AForgenet.com ? It has great libs for blob processing. Its in .NET